# Expression denotes a `value', where a `method group' was expected

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this error and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
 username.text = DB.getName(LoginSystem.userNameStatic)();
```

And the error is

> 'Expression denotes a `value`, where a `method group` was expected'

What might be the cause of this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what DB actually is (by all means, do inform us of that), the most likely cause seems to be the extra `()` you have at the end of your call to `getName()`.

I would guess it will have to be

```
username.text = DB.getName(LoginSystem.userNameStatic);
```

instead of what you have now.